# Using libraries in XCode and sharing them via Subversion

Tags: iphone, svn, xcode

We are including the mySettings library in our iPhone application to provide a settings dialog inside the application. The installation description in the Wiki of the projects describes how to include the library (see http://bitbucket.org/karemorstol/mysettings/wiki/Installation).

After following these instructions the application **compiles and runs** in the simulator as desired. When the developer **shares the project via our SVN** repository and another developer checks it out it **does not compile** on another machine because the referenced files are lying **outside of the project folder**.

Shouldn't we put all the required files into the project folder?

How is this usually done in Xcode when using a subversion repository?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all files necessary to build and run the project should be available in the repository.  You can use [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) to specify what additional files need to be checked out along with the project and where in the repository they live.